# Geometric property of a tetrahedron with 3 equal edges

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra

I haven't found a proof for this property (well, it's more of a guess), but I haven't found any counterexamples. I wanted to ask for help with either. \

Given a tetrahedron $ABCD$ where $AB = AC = AD$ (i.e these edges are of equal length), show that the line perpendicular to the triangle $BCD$ passing through the centroid of $BCD$ passes through $A$?

Is this true? (I am thinking about this in context of a different problem - the above statement is just my guess about the geometry of a tetrahedron). I'd appreciate either a reference to a proof or counterexample as I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: The perpendicular from $A$ meets $\triangle BCD$ at the *circumcenter*, not the *centroid*. To see this, let $P$ be the foot of that perpendicular. Then $\triangle ABP$, $\triangle ACP$, $\triangle ADP$ are right triangles with a common leg ($\overline{AP}$) and equal hypotenuses ($\overline{AB}\cong\overline{AC}\cong\overline{AD}$), so that their "other" legs must also be equal: $\overline{PB}\cong\overline{PC}\cong\overline{PD}$. This makes $P$ the center of the circle through $B$, $C$, $D$.

Comment: That's a very elegant way to look at it! Thanks! I'm guessing this also generalizes the same way.